# Why doesn't the PDW copy some files when updating an existing installation?

Tags: vb6

I have a fairly large application (~750k LOC) that I distribute using the Package and Deployment Wizard.  I fully understand that it would be nice to migrate to .NET (that ain't happening - see the code size above), and that the PDW is deeply flawed.  However, for the most part I've made it work well for my end users, by customizing the Setup1 application, writing a menu-driven wrapper for the Setup application, and by running it in silent mode.  (Note that the problem I'm about to describe occurred even before I started using silent mode.)

The issue I'm having is that my application requires quite a few auxiliary files, which I've added to the PDW project in the "Included files" section.  When a user does a clean installation (either from scratch, or after un-installing a previous installation), everything works fine.  However, if they simply run the installer to update the existing installation, the executable file and any OCXs I've updated get copied over the previous versions just fine, but my auxiliary files don't - I have to have the user manually delete them, and then the Setup1 program will re-install them as it should.

I've checked in the Setup.lst file, and all of the files are listed there, with their current date stamps.  In fact, in my "BuildAll.bat" file, I do the Windows equivalent of a "touch" (copy /b "TheFile.dat" +,,) to force the date stamp to be current.  However, if the file exists on the target machine, it won't be over-written even though it's older. There are no errors reported, either visibly or in the .LOG file (which is required if using the silent option).

A couple of additional points:  Some of the auxiliary files are themselves VB6 applications - just the .exe files.  Those *do* get copied correctly if they're newer than the existing files.  Other than being files with internal versioning information, there's no difference between them and the other auxiliary files (which are things like media files, or text-based .txt or .dat files).

So, what's going on, and how do I fix it (besides moving to Inno or some other solution that won't work for me...)?  Thanks in advance for any help!
~~
Mark Moulding

Comment: It might be useful to watch the installer run using Process Monitor, maybe that would give a clue as to why the files aren't being copied..?  I've used it for this sort of problem many times. Or a tool like http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor might work too, though personally I've used it less.

Comment: I've never used VB's PDW, still using the old Wise Installation System, so this might be a long shot, but maybe this [utility here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?798177-VB6-CheckLST-a-PDW-Setup-LST-file-checker) and that thread might be of some use to you.

Comment: @StayOnTarget: Thanks, using Process Monitor to watch it seems like a good idea.  The APIMonitor tool looks pretty powerful, especially being able to set breakpoints.  I'm sure it will take a bit of tinkering, since I actually want to watch a sub-process of a sub-process (my menu program, then SETUP.exe, then SETUP1.exe), but it looks like it might be worth it.

Comment: @HelO'Ween: Wow, someone else still using the old technologies!  Thanks for the pointer to CheckLST; I actually do use that tool, and it has weeded out a couple of un-distributable items, but the list seems pretty stable now.  In any case, the files I'm having a problem with are all of my own creation, rather than operating system components.